# Getting Random Records From Database For Quiz Game

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-services, windows-phone-7

I want help from you to create a query. I am new in software career and i am trying to developing a KBC Type Quiz Game for Windows Mobile Application. For That i want try to fetch random records from database and if one record is appear at one time after that record will not appear again. I use This query `"SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Quiz ORDER BY NEWID()"` but records are repeat.

My Table structure is given below.

```
ColumnName  DataType

Id          int
Que         varchar(150)
Ans1        varchar(100)
Ans2        varchar(100)
Ans3        varchar(100)
TrueAns     varchar(100)
```

I try to create a Store Procedure also which is given below

```
DECLARE @counter int, @randno int, @uBound int, @lBound int


        SELECT @uBound = Max(Id) FROM Quiz
        SELECT @lBound = Min(Id) FROM Quiz

        SELECT @randno = Round(((@uBound - @lBound) * Rand() + @lBound), 0)
        SET @Counter = 0

        WHILE @counter = 0
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS(SELECT Id FROM Quiz WHERE Id = @randno)
            BEGIN
                SET NOCOUNT OFF
                SELECT * FROM Quiz WHERE Id = @randno
                SET @counter = 1
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SELECT @randno = Round(((@uBound - @lBound -1 ) * Rand() + @lBound), 0)
            END
        END
```

but i can't get success. My Table contain this fields Que, Ans1, Ans2, Ans3, TrueAns. Please Help me for this problem. And i want to also create a web-service which return all the records

Comment: One idea might be sending pre asked questions's ids and add WHERE Id NOT IN (1,2,3,4,...) or something like that. Though I'd prefer doing that control on the codebehind, not in the sql query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i want to create a web-service for this game and i can not write all code in codebehind. if i use store procedure than my work is very less and i just call that procedure in my asmx page.

Answer (score 1):

just add a column in Quiz isread as bool and set it as a default false

then make your stored procedure like it will help you to go with webservice approach

```
DECLARE @counter int, @randno int, @uBound int, @lBound int


        SELECT @uBound = Max(Id) FROM Quiz
        SELECT @lBound = Min(Id) FROM Quiz

        SELECT @randno = Round(((@uBound - @lBound) * Rand() + @lBound), 0)
        SET @Counter = 0

        WHILE @counter = 0
        BEGIN


If(( select count(*) from Quiz where isread= true)=( select count(*) from Quiz ))
BEGIN
 update Quiz SET isread=false  
End

            IF EXISTS(SELECT Id FROM Quiz WHERE Id = @randno and isread=false )
            BEGIN
            update Quiz SET isread=true  WHERE Id = @randno                   
            SET NOCOUNT OFF
                SELECT * FROM Quiz WHERE Id = @randno

                SET @counter = 1
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SELECT @randno = Round(((@uBound - @lBound -1 ) * Rand() + @lBound), 0)
            END
        END
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but when all isread column data is true than how can make it again false so when again start quiz than so that data.

Comment: check my edited one after getting all true updating all as false

Comment: in where condition contid it occure error like incorrect syntax but in innerquery it work properly

Comment: now check its now perfect and let me know if got your solution